# For loop, Let, and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log( i );
    }, i*1000 );
}
```

Biggest thing I'm confused about here - Why does this print 1,2,3,4,5 - All one second apart? Rather than incrementing one second, and taking one second longer each time we go through the for loop? I also have another variation that confuses me, where I do a console.log(i) as the last step in the for loop, and it just instantly posts 1-5. Any help here?

Coming from C#, for the record, not sure if the behaviour exists in C# or if I'm just a bit rusty.

Thanks!

Comment: because each setTimeout is run in near parallel, because setTimeout is asynchronous

Comment: `setTimeout` isn't blocking, it's just an indicator that it will run that function in `i*1000` seconds (*asynchronous*). Basically if you say something will run in 1 second and something will run in 2 seconds, there is only a 1 second difference between those two.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quite simple. The `for` loop schedules the `timer` function for all five values. Then the timer function starts printing the numbers. Now the reason for them being printed 1 second apart is `i*1000` in `setTimeout`. As a result, 1 will be printed 1 second after it has been scheduled, 2 will be printed 2 seconds after it has been scheduled, and *approximately* 1 second after 1 has been scheduled, and so on...

See the snippet below to understand how it works. Keep in mind that `setTimeout` does not block the execution of the `for` loop.

```js
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log( i );
    }, i*1000 );
    
    console.log("Print " + i + " after " + i +" seconds.");
}

console.log("for loop completed.");
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` will place your `timer()` into the queue.
`for` loop execute very quickly nearly immediately, each loop timer() will be placed into the queue with delays: 1,2,3,4,5 seconds respectively.

`console.log(i)` will print 1-5 because of the immediate execution of for loop.

Comment: i ve tried the code:
//output
1 //1 second
2 //2 seconds
3 //3 seconds
...

what did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what the other answers have not touched upon is the **event loop**.

The event loop is a distinct execution thread than the main JS thread.
Your for loop would execute in the main JS thread, pushing each timeout on the event loop which would be executed in the event loop as scheduled. The time scale of events would look something like this.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to set a breakpoint and watch the value of 'i' each iteration. You would figure out it increments and consequently the timeout set is successively more by 1s.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you are looking for
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000*i);