# setTimeout function unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, settimeout

I have the following code to append iframes from an elements array in batch sizes of 10 with a time interval of 10 seconds per batch. Batches is an array which has a JSON object with start and end indexes for each batch. Append function appends the iframe with code to the DOM.

**Current behavior:** JS waits for 10 seconds and calls the append function together while appending all the iframes in one go without waiting for 10 seconds each batch.

**Expected behavior:** JS waits for 10 seconds before appending each batch or each append function call.

```
batches.forEach(function (x) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        append(x, elements);
        console.log('appending'+x);
    }, 10000);
});
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45767325/5894241

Comment: Your foreach loop just loops through all elements without stopping.  So it's creating a setTimeout for each element very quickly.  They all then wait the 10 seconds, and then execute all at once.  If you want them to execute at different times, then you have to give them each a different delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setTimeout` does not pause execution so your code is the equivalent of

```
setTimeout(..., 10000)
setTimeout(..., 10000)
setTimeout(..., 10000)
// etc
```

where each timeout call is set to execute at roughly the same time, 10 seconds from now.

You're going to have to increase the timeout in each iteration. Something like this...

```
batches.forEach((x, i) => { // where "i" is the current, zero-based index
  setTimeout(() => {
    // etc
  }, 10000 * (i + 1))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create a function to process the batches like this:

```
function processBatch(batches, delay){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // get the first element / child in batches
        var batch = batches[0];
        // process your batch the way you want it
        console.log(batch);
        // remove the already processed batch
        batches.splice(0, 1);
        if (batches.length > 0){
            // process the remainder batches
            processBatch(batches, delay)
        } else {
            console.log('done');
        }
    }, delay)
}
```

call it with:

```
var batches = [1, 2, 3, 4];
processBatch(batches, 100000);
```

to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/pa64vqxr/ (don't forget to open your browser console)